# How to Authenticate Xero API with Integromat

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, xero-api, make.com

I'm a bit of a newbie to using APIs, and in particular OAuth 2.0. I am trying to use Integromat to pull a financial report from the Xero API, but am stuck on trying to get the connection to work. This is the error I receive after selecting the organization I want to authenticate:

[image]

Here are the inputs I'm using in Integromat:

**- Flow Type:** Authorization Code

**- Authorize URI:** https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_Client_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/oauth2&scope=openid profile email accounting.reports.read&state=123

**- Token URI:** https://identity.xero.com/connect/token

**- Client ID:** My_Client_ID

**- Client Secret:** My_Client_Secret

Here is what my current setup looks like:

[image]

**Addendum from original post:**

When I click "Continue", I receive this screen:

[image]

When I click "Login" I come to this screen:

[image]

After selecting my organization from the dropdown and then clicking "Connect" I receive the aforementioned error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try replacing the spaces between your scopes with %20 ?

Comment: Just tried that. Instead of the error in my original post, that results in "Error Code: 500"

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks ok - and you seem to understand messages, but it is not clear at what point the error occurs:

- During the UI's login redirect, which gets an authorization code
- During the authorization code grant, which swaps the code for tokens
- During the API call, which should supply the OAuth 2.0 access token in the Authorization header

To troubleshoot I would use a tool such as Fiddler and view messages, as in [my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/). This often helps to identify malformed messages, and allows you to view full error details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To be honest, the blog post was a bit over my head. I added some more context and screenshots to my original post, so I am hoping that helps to identify the problem I am experiencing. My guess is the problem is with the token swap, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I just meant that if you could capture the OAuth messages and post the one that's failing you'll get the best response